# Bootstrap nested column border issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]

I am using bootstrap 4 grid system and I have a layout like the image above, the issue I am getting is the border is not aligned at the bottom row.
Since I am using nested columns in (first and second row) which are eventually four columns. But at the last row I have two columns. I need last row border to match with the above row.

Please help. Thanks
[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/m0L73pga/1/)

```html
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7 border">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="adf_bd_nationality" class="bg-gray-light d-flex border-right  border-bottom-0 align-items-center col-7 col-form-label text-black col-form-label-sm">Registration (Tail No.)</label>
            <div class="col-5 bg-white">
              <input class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 bg-white border border-md-left-0  ">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="adf_bd_serialNo" class="bg-gray-light d-flex border-md-right border-right border-bottom-0  border-top-0 align-items-center col-6 col-form-label text-black col-form-label-sm">Serial No.</label>
            <div class="col-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control text-black text-center " id="adf_bd_serialNo" name="adf_bd_serialNo" onkeypress="return /[0-9a-zA-Z]/i.test(event.key)" maxlength="10">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7 border border-top-0 ">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="adf_bd_manufacturer" class="bg-gray-light d-flex border-right border-md-bottom-0 align-items-center col-7 col-form-label text-black col-form-label-sm">Manufacturer</label>
            <div class="col-5 bg-white">
              <select name="adf_bd_manufacturer" id="adf_bd_manufacturer" class="my-select form-control">
                <option value="" class="bg-black">Select</option>
                <option value="Airbus" class="bg-black">Airbus</option>
                <option value="Boeing" class="bg-black">Boeing</option>
                <option value="Bombardier" class="bg-black">Bombardier</option>
                <option value="Embraer" class="bg-black">Embraer</option>
                <option value="McDonnell Douglas" class="bg-black">McDonnell Douglas</option>
                <option value="Tupoloev" class="bg-black">Tupoloev</option>
                <option value="Cessna" class="bg-black">Cessna</option>
                <option value="Cirrus Design" class="bg-black">Cirrus Design</option>
                <option value="Diamond" class="bg-black">Diamond</option>
                <option value="Mooney" class="bg-black">Mooney</option>
                <option value="Piper" class="bg-black">Piper</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 bg-white border border-top-0 border-md-left-0 ">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="adf_bd_ICAO" class="bg-gray-light d-flex border border-md-right  border-bottom-0 border-md-bottom-0 border-top-0 border-left-0 align-items-center col-6 col-form-label text-black col-form-label-sm">Type ICAO</label>
            <div class="col-6 ">
              <input type="text" class="form-control text-black text-center" id="adf_bd_ICAO" name="adf_bd_ICAO" data-inputmask="'regex': '[a-zA-Z0-9]', 'repeat': 4, 'placeholder': ''" autocomplete="off" inputmode="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row border border-top-0 ">
        <label for="adf_bd_engineTypes" class="bg-gray-light d-flex  border-right border-bottom-0 border-bottom align-items-center col-4 col-form-label text-black col-form-label-sm" style="">Engine Type(s)</label>
        <div class="col-8 adf_bd_engineTypesCon bg-white" style="">
          <input type="text" class="form-control text-black required " id="adf_bd_engineTypes" name="adf_bd_engineTypes" data-inputmask="'regex': '^[0-9a-zA-Z]', 'repeat': 15, 'placeholder': ''">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use tables? Its much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because there are many nested `row` inside another `row`. So bootstrap divides nested `row` to 12 columns.

What we want is to create just four columns and then put content there:

```
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label for="adf_bd_nationality" class="bg-gray-light text-black">
          Registration (Tail No.)
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 border-left">
      <input class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-2  border-left">
      <label for="adf_bd_serialNo" class="bg-gray-light d-flex  align-items-center col-form-label text-black 
          col-form-label-sm">
      Serial No.
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2  border-left">
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-black text-center " id="adf_bd_serialNo" name="adf_bd_serialNo" onkeypress="return /[0-9a-zA-Z]/i.test(event.key)" maxlength="10">
    </div>  
  </div>
  
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label for="adf_bd_nationality" class="bg-gray-light text-black">
          Registration (Tail No.)
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 border-left">
      <input class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-2  border-left">
      <label for="adf_bd_serialNo" class="bg-gray-light d-flex  align-items-center col-form-label text-black 
          col-form-label-sm">
      Serial No.
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2  border-left">
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-black text-center " id="adf_bd_serialNo" name="adf_bd_serialNo" onkeypress="return /[0-9a-zA-Z]/i.test(event.key)" maxlength="10">
    </div>  
  </div>
  
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label for="adf_bd_nationality" class="bg-gray-light text-black">
          Registration (Tail No.)
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 border-left">
      <input class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-2  border-left">
      <label for="adf_bd_serialNo" class="bg-gray-light d-flex  align-items-center col-form-label text-black 
          col-form-label-sm">
      Serial No.
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2  border-left">
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-black text-center " id="adf_bd_serialNo" name="adf_bd_serialNo" onkeypress="return /[0-9a-zA-Z]/i.test(event.key)" maxlength="10">
    </div>  
  </div>
  
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label for="adf_bd_nationality" class="bg-gray-light text-black">
          Registration (Tail No.)
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 border-left">
      The right border
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't work for me, I need to have 2 columns in the last row.

Comment: @AhsanAli oops, please, see my updated answer